# AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer still showing after segue

Tags: ios, avcapturesession, uistoryboardsegue

I'm using Storyboards and I have my first view with a AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer in it to show a live stream of my Camera input. That works fine. However when I try to modally segue to another view, the AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer view is still showing in the background. of the view instead of the set black colored background of the new view. I've tried to use the removeFromSuperLayer inside the:

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
```

method. However this doesn't work.

Any suggestions on how to get rid of this?

Comment: Can you post some of your code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At first, stop the video

```
[previewLayer.session stopRunning]
```

at second, remove video output if you dont need it

```
[previewLayer.session removeOutput:AVMediaTypeVideo]
```

if this wont help, try to invoke

```
setNeedsDisplay
```

on super layer